# other way to say " more to it than that "

Tags: synonyms

I will be really appreciated if anyone suggests any other form of saying " but there is more to it than that ". I have issued this question because I am looking for a graceful way to start a new paragraph which contains extensive information about previous paragraphs presumably . any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of possible phrases you could use, depending on the exact situation. A few ideas:

"Further"

"Additionally"

"However, things are not quite that simple"

"However, there are other significant issues to consider"